# How to fire up a function when clicking on a link and then pass a class from that link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="sshjd839djjd blahclass"><a onclick="doSomething()">Blah Blah</a></li>
```

So when I click my link `doSomething()` is triggered and I want to grab `sshjd839djjd`. I have many links with different keys like this one which I need to grab correct data.

I don't know much about Javascript and jQuery but I need it to make admin panel which I would use to manage my data in Firebase, just to explain what I'm doing.

I tried to avoid `onClick` and use `.click` but that didn't work.

Can somebody help me a bit please?

So what should go in:

```
function doSomething() {
   // grab class which is actually a child key from Firebase which I already implemented
   // do Firebase magic, I will know this once I get that key
}
```

Keys/classes are added like this:

```
var resultVetRef = new Firebase("https://myappname.firebaseio.com/data/users");
        resultVetRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          var key = snapshot.key();
          var data = snapshot.val();
          var name = data.name;
          var city = data.city;
          $("#results").append($("<li class=\"" + key + " blahclass\">" + "<a onClick=\"grabVet()\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>"));
        });
```

Comment: what does this mean `I want to grab specialKey`?

Comment: what format will specialkey be in? is it a random string of letters and numbers?

Comment: pls provide actual example with actual classes names and result

Comment: where is your special key?

Comment: How the 'key' are inserted on Li? You use php and do an echo?

Comment: I edited my initial post. So every link has a class with child key from Firebase which I programmatically added (this is not important), and when I click on some item I want to grab that key/class from that item so I can use it for connecting Firebase later.

Comment: This is important (I programmatically added), because the answer of @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani using data-key, can be a better approach for your case

Comment: Better pratice, then using class

Comment: Ok I added code that generates my list.

Comment: Instead of 
<li class=\"" + key + " blahclass\">" + "<a onClick=\"grabVet()\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>, use <li class=\"blahclass\" data-key='" + key + "'>" + "<a onClick=\"grabVet()\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for your example

```
<li class="sshjd839djjd blahclass"><a>Blah Blah</a></li>

$('a').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).closest('li')[0].classList.item(0) );
});
```

using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and item method.

or if you want to use your own `doSomething`

```
<li class="sshjd839djjd blahclass"><a onclick="doSomething(this)">Blah Blah</a></li>

function doSomething(thisObj)
{
  alert($(thisObj).closest("li")[0].classList.item(0)); 
}
```

Comment: well with this approach key must be the first class, otherwise it will return wrong key

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yes, which is what OP has mentioned. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I like this approach. This link is deep down in my site, how do I trigger .click on that link in particular?

Comment: @KiraArik `how do I trigger .click` You need to traverse to that link and do the same.

Comment: Well I have ol with id #results and then it goes into list items. I use Foundation accordion and it somehow grabs .accordion-item instead of li class

Answer (score 2):

add the key as data to the `li`

```
var resultVetRef = new Firebase("https://myappname.firebaseio.com/data/users");
        resultVetRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          var key = snapshot.key();
          var data = snapshot.val();
          var name = data.name;
          var city = data.city;
          $("#results").append($("<li class=\"" + key + " blahclass\" data-key=\""+ key +"\">" + "<a onClick=\"grabVet()\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>"));
        });
```

Then get it like:

```
<li class="sepcialKey blahclass" data-key="sepcialKey"><a>Blah Blah</a></li>

$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('li').data('key'));
});
```

Here is the Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/ffyLgg3s/

Comment: That is a better pratice

Comment: Can you understand Kira? The data called 'key' is added to li, and you can retrieve with $(element).data('key').

Comment: Oh not quite. I need to try code from gurvinder372. I just wanted to make easier to manipulate data in Firebase. If don't manage to do this I will have to update everything manually :(

Answer (score 0):

*ClassList* method gives you an array with all classes of the element.
In your case it will return array `["specialKey", "blahclass"]` for your `<li>` element.

```
function doSomething() {
      // get the firs element of classList array and asign it to a variable
      var specialKey = this.parentElement.classList[0]; // "this" keyword is the reference to clicked element, "parentElement" give you "li" element reference
      // do Firebase magic, I will know this once I get that key
}
```

Or modify your append code:

```
var resultVetRef = new Firebase("https://myappname.firebaseio.com/data/users");
resultVetRef.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  var key = snapshot.key();
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var name = data.name;
  var city = data.city;
  // create li element
  var li = $("<li class=\"blahclass\"></li>");
  // create a element
  var a = $("<a>" + name + ", " + city + "</a>");
  a.on("click", function () {
    // when a clicked execute "doSomething" passing key as parameter
    doSomething(key);
  })
  // append a to li
  li.append(a);
  //append li to #results
  $("#results").append(li);
});
```

Comment: This returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined